# Convert wifi to wired using wireless router

Tags: wifi, bridge, wireless-bridge, bridge-router, tp-link

I have a TP-Link WR740N,  a Raspberry Pi (With only an ethernet port for Network), and a Wifi connection. Is it possible to use the wireless router to bridge the Pi with the Wifi connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, you need to set the TP Link up as a client to your WIFI this creates a WIFI bridge.

To do that you need to access it's admin page via your browser, log in, find client or ethernet bridge mode. It will ask for an SSID, this is your wifi network name. It will also need your wifi password and may ask for the encryption type your wifi is set to.

When it comes to it's IP address, you will have 2 choices, dynamic or static, dyanmic will get an IP from your home network. But finding it again after it's been asigned an IP can be tricky. Or set it as static, you need to match your homes Subnet mask and choose an IP thats inside your home networks but not used by any other devices.

Once it's connected you will want to make sure the TPLinks DHCP is turned off as your home network more than likely has a DHCP ( gives out IP address ).

I've done this for my development boards that only have Ethernet using this device.